# Change default sorting order for multiple specific woocommerce product categories

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the default orderby for multiple product categories, but can't work out how to adapt the code found here [Cant change default sorting order of specific woocommerce category to 'popularity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308258/cant-change-default-sorting-order-of-specific-woocommerce-category-to-popularit) to apply the change to more than one category.

Here's the code I currently have that is changing the default orderby for my comic book preorders category:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {

    $product_category = 'comic-book-pre-orders';

    if ( is_product_category( $product_category ) ) {
        return 'sku_asc';
    }
    else {
        return 'date';
}
}
```

Ideally I'd be able to apply the custom orderby to my 'comic-book-subscriptions' category as well as a couple of others potentially.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Kind regards,
JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I managed to work it out!

Here's the code I'm now using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {

    $product_category = array( 'comic-book-pre-orders', 'comic-book-subscriptions' );

    if ( is_product_category( $product_category ) ) {
        return 'sku_asc';
    }
    else {
        return 'date';
}
}
```

If anyone has a better approach please let me know :)